# Is it possible to have 0 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Can you have 0 rep?

If not, what am I going to do with all these counting from 0 jokes I found under my bed?

Comment: Care to share some of these jokes? I'm intrigued.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, 1 is the minimum rep level. Maybe you can recycle them?